# How to print line number for specific condition in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

My xml is

```
<File>
    <Sub_Function_1>
        <Messages>
            <Setting>
                <Data>
                    <Label>Setting_1</Label>
                    <Value>
                        <Measure>
                            <Data>Area</Data>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Data>2000</Data>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Data>0</Data>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Integer>10000</Integer>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Integer>12000</Integer>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                        </Measure>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Label>Setting_2</Label>
                    <Value>
                        <Measure>
                            <Data>Area_2</Data>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Integer>2000</Integer>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Data>0</Data>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Integer>10000</Integer>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Data>12000</Data>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                        </Measure>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Label>Setting_3</Label>
                    <Value>
                        <Measure>
                            <Data>Area_2</Data>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Speed>2000</Speed>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Data>0</Data>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Distance>10000</Distance>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Data>12000</Data>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                        </Measure>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
            </Setting>
        </Messages>
    </Sub_Function_1>
</File>
```

Here I want to print line number if both `Condition` and `Value` of Bound have different elements.
for ex here line 14(Data) and line 22(Integer) doesn't match , line 17(Data) and line 25(Integer) doesn't match , line 64(Speed) and line 72(Distance) doesn't match.

My code where I was trying to match elements of condition:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('C:/Python/Project.xml')
for eqs in doc.xpath('//File[.//Measure//*[2]/Value/*[1]]'):
 for vqs in doc.xpath('//File[.//Measure//*[3]/Value/*[1]]'):
  if eqs != vqs :
       for e in eqs:
        print("Measure", e.sourceline)
```

It's not printing any line no
output lines expected:

```
line no. 12, 15, 60
```

So here value and conditions are not having same elements for which i want to print lines

[image]

Here Value and condition have same elements so I don't want to print lines
[image]

Here Value don't have same element so i want to print line of value

[image]

Comment: @mzjn if I understand you want me to add more code....I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your conditions correctly, this should work:

```
for target in doc2.xpath('//Data//following-sibling::Bound[not(Value=Condition)]'):
    print(target.sourceline)
```

Output should be something like

```
10
18
34
42
58
66
```

EDIT:

Again, if I understand you correctly, this should get you at least close enough to where you want to get. Of course, you can modify it as you see fit:

```
for k in doc2.xpath('//Measure//Data[following-sibling::Bound]'):
    val1 = k.xpath('following-sibling::Bound[1]/Value/*')[0]
    val2 = k.xpath('following-sibling::Bound[2]/Value/*')[0]
    if val1.tag !=val2.tag:
        print(val1.tag,"--",val1.sourceline,val2.tag,"--",val2.sourceline)
   
    cond1 = k.xpath('following-sibling::Bound[1]/Condition/*')[0]
    cond2 = k.xpath('following-sibling::Bound[2]/Condition/*')[0]
    if cond1.tag !=cond2.tag:
        print(cond1.tag,"--",cond1.sourceline,val2.tag,"--",cond2.sourceline)
```

Output in this case:

```
Data -- 12 Integer -- 20
Data -- 15 Integer -- 23
Speed -- 60 Distance -- 68
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to print lines if element Value / Condition of both Bounds are not be equal.
Here line 34 and 42 not required
if i change it to this `[not(Value=Value)]` nothing is getting printed

Comment: @Anonymous I must have misunderstood your question then; can you edit the question and clarify **exactly** what you're looking for?

Comment: I have added picture to clarify my question

Comment: @Anonymous I believe I get it now, but it's still not clear; in your third example, you say you "want to print line of value" - but there are two `<Value>` elements: once with `<Speed>` child and one with `<Distance>`; which of these two `<Value>` elements are you looking for? Same with the other examples.

Comment: Any element line it can print either <Speed> or <Distance>
My aim is to print only line no if elements are not equal under Value or Condition